# NoClassDefinitionError with simple bean configuration

Tags: spring-xd

```
<bean id="xmlItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
        <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="SomeElement" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="jaxb2unmarshaller" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jaxb2unmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
                <list>
                     <value>org.MappedClass</value>
                </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

I started with multi step job and have issue when packaged as the job module in the spring-xd, I stripped all the other beans from the configuration and finally figured the issue was coming due to the above two beans.
The spring-oxm jar is present in the custom modules lib. I am using spring-xd 1.0.0.RC1.

I don't want to put the jars in to the server lib, all the required libraries should be part of the custom module lib directory.
How to get it working?

If I place the spring-oxm jar in the spring-xd/lib directory the error goes but then I get the other errors too.

I guess the real reason for the NoClassDefError could be the missing dependencies and the error does not indicate the information about the missing dependent class.

Any inputs would be appreciated?

Comment: where's the stack trace?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/oxm/Unmarshaller
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1855)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:199)

Comment: do you have spring-oxm*.jar in your classpath?

Comment: yes, please read my initial post it mentions "The spring-oxm jar is present in the custom modules lib. I am using spring-xd 1.0.0.RC1."

Answer (score 0):

The information provided is not sufficient to conclude anything. However, you could check the second last line of the code block provided above. The closing `<property>` tag is missing or it's a TYPO while writing the code here.

Comment: It is typo while posting here. The other error that I was referring when I moved the spring-oxm jar to the spring-xd lib is        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/oxm/Unmarshaller
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1855)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:199)

Answer (score 0):

The module's dependent jars should go in the module's lib/ directory if they are not on the server class path already. Spring XD 1.1 has improved support for module packaging but in 1.0 you need to install the jars manually. Also, I would suggest upgrading to 1.1.0.M2 or  1.0.3.RELEASE at least.

Comment: Having the module dependent jars in the module's lib directory is what I have been doing, but that is not working with the couple of beans that I have defined. You can try it too. If I put the jar in the server classpath I get the following error                          java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller] to required type [org.springframework.oxm.Unmarshaller] for property 'unmarshaller': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Comment: >>Spring XD 1.1 has improved support for module packaging but in 1.0 >>you need to install the jars manually

Comment: I am seeing the same behaviour with spring-xd-1.1.0.M2, the issue is easy to reproduce. I would like to hear more from the spring-xd developers before I raise a JIRA about it.

Comment: I have created the JIRA https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-2578. It contains the simple application which will simulate the issue.